# Get list of computers in a domain using .Net

Tags: c#, network-programming

How to get list of computer names in a domain using C# ?

Answer (score 8):

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public void PrintComputersInDomain (string domainName)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://" + domainName);
    de.Children.SchemaFilter.Add ("computer");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry c in de.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (c.Name);
    }
}
```

from http://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2008/01/25/enumerating-computers-in-a-domain.aspx

Comment: If you have Organizational Units and computers inside them then you have to enumerate through the OU's too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows domain, you can run an LDAP query against the directory to pull back a list of Machine Accounts