# How can I get a list of computers connected to the network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of all computers on a network w/o DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105676/get-a-list-of-all-computers-on-a-network-w-o-dns)

I am creating an application where you can send information between computers on a network. The computers listen for connections and can send information to another computer that is on the network. I need to know how to get a list of hostnames or IP addresses on the network the computer is connected to.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: Are you in a domain? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464983/get-list-of-computers-in-a-domain-using-net

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973871/net-get-devices-from-network
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105676/get-a-list-of-all-computers-on-a-network-w-o-dns
or this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using

Comment: Could you just ping -b ?

Comment: I'm not in a domain... And when I put in "ping -b" in the command prompt it says "Bad option -b".

Comment: I have tried using netapi32.dll... It didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know where I got this code from anymore.
The last piece of code is from me (getIPAddress())

It reads your ip to get the base ip of the network.

Credits go to the author:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ipBase = getIPAddress();
        string [] ipParts = ipBase.Split('.');
        ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + "." + ipParts[2] + ".";
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();

            Ping p = new Ping();
            p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
            p.SendAsync(ip, 100, ip);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            if (resolveNames)
            {
                string name;
                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                    name = hostEntry.HostName;
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    name = "?";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is up: ({2} ms)", ip, name, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is up: ({1} ms)", ip, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                upCount++;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Reply == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
        }
    }

    public static string getIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very good implementation, but is there a way I can have it throw an error if the computer is not connected to a network (either just not connected to the Internet or connected to the Internet with a direct connection)?

Comment: I think you will find here, what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314213/checking-network-status-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you... I'll make use of this... :)